# Enable Bluetooth modem internet connection sharing in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, connection-sharing

I am trying to use internet over Sony Xperia P using my laptop's bluetooth connection. So the idea is to make use of internet connection from my laptop and extend it via bluetooth so that i can use it on my phone.

Normally the other way around works fine. However after installing all the drivers, in window's bluetooth settings i see this option:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL8ZG.png]

My question is, how can I enable this option?

> Allow remote devices to use your modem to connect to the internet or to send a fax

How can I enable this?